# Segmentation fault in ROS application with iplmage

Tags: pointers, opencv, segmentation-fault, iplimage, ros

I'm trying to detect a blob on a video feed with **cvBlob** lib in my **ROS** node.
I think, I made a mistake with **pointers**, but I can't figure out where.
Moreover, do I have to free some of this variable?

```
Mat& corridorProces(Mat& resultImg)
{   
    Mat srcMat=resultImg.clone();
    cvtColor( resultImg, resultImg, CV_RGB2GRAY );
    IplImage src= resultImg.clone();
    IplImage *src_g= new IplImage(src);
    IplImage *src_g_inv=new IplImage(src);
    cvThreshold(src_g, src_g_inv,35,255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    cvThreshold(src_g, src_g,40,255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);    
    IplImage *labelImg=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src_g), IPL_DEPTH_LABEL, 1);
    cvb::CvBlobs blobs;
    unsigned int result=cvb::cvLabel(src_g, labelImg, blobs);   
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use cvCopy to copy an image to another. Furthermore, You need to release the images using cvReleaseImage(&image);

Comment: thanks @Ahmed Saleh, I used `IplImage *src_g=cvCloneImage(&src);` and now its working.